# Argument of function as function in C (return value 3221225477)

Tags: c

- [Warning] passing argument 4 of `volume` from incompatible pointer type
- [Note] expected `ActionT` but argument is of type `float (*)(float *, float *)`
- [Warning] passing argument 4 of `volume_without_typedef` from incompatible pointer type
- [Note] expected `float (*)(float,  float)` but argument is of type `float (*)(float *, float *)`

Function as the argument of another function is not working well.
I did google. I have no idea how to deal with that. 
The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
float square(float *a, float *b);
typedef float( * ActionT )( float, float );
float volume( float *a, float *b, float *h, ActionT pAction );
float volume_without_typedef( float *a, float *b, float *h, float( * pAction )( float, float ) );
int main()
{
    float a,b,h;
    float *wa, *wb, *wh;
    printf("Give values: a, b, h(height):\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a,&b,&h);
    wa=&a;
    wb=&b;
    wh=&h;
    printf("Volume = %f\n", volume( wa, wb, wh, square ));
    printf("Volume without typedef = %f\n", volume_without_typedef( wa, wb, wh, square ));
    return 0;
}

float square(float *a, float *b)
{
    return (*a * *b);
}
float volume( float *a, float *b, float *h, ActionT pAction )
{
    return (pAction( *a, *b ) * *h );
}
float volume_without_typedef( float *a, float *b, float *h, float( * pAction )( float, float ) )
{
    return ( pAction( *a, *b ) * *h );
}
```

Comment: What is unclear with the diagnostic messages?

Comment: You're passing a function with the signature `float(*)(float *, float *)` where `float(*)(float, float)` is expected for the first warning. The exact opposite is happening in the second warning.

Comment: There's really no need to pass pointers to `float` in any of these functions.

Comment: Convert large decimal numbers you see back when you test your app to hex.  3221225477 == 0xC0000005.  That is not a "return value", that is the exit code of your program.  Google has many hits for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `function pointer` declaration

```
typedef float( * ActionT )( float, float );
```

says `ActionT` is a **function pointer** that can points to *any function* and that function should take *2 floats as input* and should return `one float`, now you should follow these.

Next trying to point `ActionT` to `square()` function but `square()` takes argument as 2 `float*` not `float`. thats why compiler gives warnings.

So you should change `square()` function as below. Also you are calling function pointer wrongly in `volume()` function.

```
(pAction( *a, *b ) * *h ); ---> (*pAction) ( *a, *b ) * (*h);
```

Complete code

```
float square(float a, float b) {
        return ((a) * (b));
}
float volume( float *a, float *b, float *h, ActionT pAction)  {
        return  (*pAction) ( *a, *b ) * (*h);
}
float volume_without_typedef( float *a, float *b, float *h, float( * pAction )( float, float ) ) {
        return ( pAction( *a, *b ) * *h );
}

int main() {
        float a,b,h;
        float *wa, *wb, *wh;
        printf("Give values: a, b, h(height):\n");
        scanf("%f %f %f", &a,&b,&h);
        wa=&a;
        wb=&b;
        wh=&h;
        printf("Volume = %f\n", volume( wa, wb, wh, square ));
        printf("Volume without typedef = %f\n", volume_without_typedef( wa, wb, wh, square ));
        return 0;
}
```